# Cron on Ubuntu AWS with Python/Anaconda Virtual Environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cron

Previously was using Fedora, and I was calling cron jobs using this method, which worked perfectly:

```
source /home/me/miniconda/bin/activate me_dev; python /home/me/avant_bi/g_parse.py
```

Now this throw an error in the cron logs:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

I've tried switching `source` for a `.` to no avail, as I read something I didn't fully understand about Ubuntu cron not working with the source call.

I've also tried

```
/home/me/miniconda/envs/me_dev/python /home/me/avant_bi/g_parse.py
```

Which is the location of the python I use when I activate the environment generally, but that seemingly is doing nothing (no logs of it running in cron).

I've tried multiple variations of this to no avail. Any ideas for what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

default shell on ubuntu is /bin/dash so /bin/sh will be a symlink to that.  `source` is a bash builtin.  to run cron jobs as bash put `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the cron file

Comment: Awesome! Couldn't find anything for this. Had also tried some PATH= at the top, and that wasn't working. Thanks!